# Can I buy an unlocked iPhone in Japan?

Tags: iphone, unlock, apple-store

I'm going to Japan (Tokyo, being more specific) on April, and I'd like to buy an iPhone there. I made some research and found mixed information about whether is possible to buy an unlocked iPhone 7 256GB in an Apple Store in Tokyo.

[This post](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/bought-iphone-se-in-japan-but-its-locked-what-to-do.1988597/) for example, is from someone that bought an iPhone and it didn't work in US. But MadDane said in Aug 18, 2016:

> I have lived in Japan and have friends that came to visit while I was there that bought an iPhone 6s while there. This was at an Apple Store in Tokyo, but it was unlocked and works perfectly overseas. So you should definitely be able to get the same.

So, is it possible to buy an **unlocked iPhone** in Japan at an Apple Store to use it later with a GSM carrier in Brazil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to buy a unlocked iPhone at any apple-store in japan, but there are the following issues:

- LTE Freqency Band does not match (Japan 2,1 GHz / Brazil 2.6 GHz). That means, LTE will not work. You will need the model A1778 and in Japan you can only buy the model A1779: http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/
- You can not claim any warranty replacements outside of japan